# Arbitrary code folding in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-folding

I know that we can fold `methods`,`if statement` and ... .But I want to fold arbitrary part of code that is written in a method.I guess that in `NetBeans` we can do this:

```
// <editor-fold desc="describe what is in here">
Your code goes here...
// </editor-fold>
```

But now I'm developing in Eclipse.[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829006/1043882) a propose,but it did not work for me.Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? How did that solution not work for you? Did you add the braces? Did you not see the - sign allowing you to collapse what was in between the braces?

Comment: @Karan I'm using Eclipse Helios.I added braces and I did not see any sign(- or + ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found `Coffee-Bytes` plugin.I downloaded it from [this link](http://sites.google.com/site/bkosarzyckistorage1/eclipse-folding-plugin.tar.gz) and [here](http://kosiara87.blogspot.de/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html) I found a guide for using it.You can see more details in these references:

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706723/1043882)
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947590/1043882)